# AWS VPC DNS for private endpoint not resolved in one account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have two VPC's setup, 172.31.x.x and 10.0.x.x, and the same setup in three different AWS accounts (test, qa and production).

In the 172 VPC I have an Elastic Beanstalk instance which has an internal DNS as `http://test1.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` and in the 10 VPC I have a bunch of Lambda functions.
The Lambda functions call the Elastic Beanstalk instance over HTTP.

In two of the accounts the DNS is resolved fine for `http://[env].eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` to the 172.31.x.x address from the Lambdas, but in the "production" account it is not resolved and requests time out.

Changing `http://production1.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` to the 172.31.x.x address for the Lambdas it works fine so security groups, routing tables and peering is fine from the network perspective, but DNS resolution is not working.

The VPC/subnet setup are identical as far as I can see between the accounts, except for the peering, which is setup the other way round in `production`, so it is `Requester 10.0.x.x` and `Accepter 172.31.x.x`, while the other two accounts (where it works has) `Requester 172.31.x.x` and `Accepter 10.0.x.x`.
However the DNS setting for the peering is set "bidirectonal" so according to the documentation it should work both ways...

[image: Peering DNS]

What am I missing here, or what else can I check?